# Find element in array that matches selection and write to that row of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, overwrite

The good news is I'm to the very last part of this project, the bad news is i can't figure it out. My program consist of two forms. The first form is only relevant at this moment because it is where I originally load the text file into a dictionary.

```
class SharedMethods
{
    public static void LoadDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> vendorPhones)
    {
        string currentLine;
        string[] fields = new string[2];
        StreamReader vendorReader = new StreamReader("Vendor.txt");

        while (vendorReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            currentLine = vendorReader.ReadLine();
            fields = currentLine.Split(',');

            vendorPhones.Add(fields[1], fields[6]);
            string[] name = { fields[1] };
            string[] phone = { fields[6] };
        }
        vendorReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Now the second form is what is important. This form is opened from the first form and allows the user to select a name from a combobox, and the phone number that belongs to that name is displayed in a text box. The user can then type in the text box to overwrite that name and click save to save it to a text file. My problem is I can't figure out how to get the writing function to find the selected name in the text and then write over the current phone element in that row. Here is my code for this form:

```
public partial class UpdateVendor : Form
{
    public UpdateVendor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> vendorPhones = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void UpdateVendor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SharedMethods.LoadDictionary(vendorPhones);
        foreach (string name in vendorPhones.Keys)
        {
            cboVendors.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }

    private void cboVendors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        string selectedName = cboVendors.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string phone = vendorPhones[selectedName];
        txtPhone.Text = phone.ToString();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SharedMethods.LoadDictionary(vendorPhones);
        //string selectedName = cboVendors.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //string newPhone;
        //newPhone = txtPhone.Text;

        //using (var sw = new StreamWriter("Vendors.txt"))
        //{

        //}
        // I've tried a lot of things but can't get any to work. 

    }
```

Sorry if the code makes you cringe in disgust. I'm just learning code and I'm ecstatic that it works half the time.

To add, here is how the program looks when running: 
[Second form running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3pbq.png)

Comment: You said, "This form is opened from the first form and allows the user to select a name from a combobox, and the phone number that belongs to that name is displayed in a text box. The user can then type in the text box to overwrite that name and click save to save it to a text file." Don't you mean the user can type in the text box to overwrite the **Phone Number**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that, because you are not capturing all the data when reading the file in the first place, you will have to be a little tricky about writing it back so that you don't lose any data.

What we can do is re-read the entire file back into an array, then search each line in the array for the one that contains our vendor and original phone number. When we find that line, update the phone number part to the new number. Then, write all the lines back to the file again

Here's one way to do it:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Grab the selected vendor name
    string selectedName = cboVendors.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // Grab the original phone number for this vendor
    string originalPhone = vendorPhones[selectedName];            

    // Read all the file lines into an array:
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("Vendor.txt");

    // Now we iterate over the file lines one by one, looking for a match
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
    {
        // Break the line into parts to see if this line is the one we need to update
        string[] lineParts = fileLines[i].Split(',');
        string name = lineParts[1];
        string phone = lineParts[6];

        // Compare this line's name and phone with our originals
        if (name == selectedName && phone == originalPhone)
        {
            // It's a match, so we will update the phone number part of this line
            lineParts[6] = txtPhone.Text;

            // And then we join the parts back together and assign it to the line again
            fileLines[i] = string.Join(",", lineParts);

            // Now we can break out of the loop since we updated our vendor info
            break;
        }
    }

    // Finally, we can write all the lines back to the file
    File.WriteAllLines("Vendor.txt", fileLines);

    // May not be necessary, but if you're not reading back from the file right away
    // then update the dictionary with the new phone number for this vendor
    vendorPhones[selectedName] = txtPhone.Text;
}
```

---

Ideally, however, you would capture ALL the data when you read the file, and for each line in the file you would create a new `Vendor` object that had properties representing each comma-separated value. Then, these `Vendor` objects could be stored in a `List<Vendor>`. Now you have a collection of strongly typed objects that you can display and manipulate, and when you're all done you can just write them all back to the file in a similar manner.

But that wasn't your question, and it sounds like you may not be quite there yet...

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Thanks for the help on my question earlier today as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string selectedName = cboVendors.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string phone = vendorPhones[selectedName];
            if (vendorPhones.ContainsKey(selectedName))
            {
                vendorPhones[selectedName] = phone;
            }
            else
            {
                vendorPhones.Add(selectedName, phone);
            }
```